# websphere application server 5.1 on win 7

Tags: websphere, server

I have installed RAD 7.0 on win 7 64 bit, with WebSphere v5.1 Test Environment, sometimes its start but most of the times hit 'Server WebSphere v5.1 Test Environment Test Environment @ localhost failed to start', how can check this, anyone can guide for this,

Comment: Update to WebSphere 8.5.5 or WebSphere Liberty. WebSphere 5.1 is ancient addition and from many years no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

My experience only goes back to WAS v6 but assuming 5.1 is the same there will be a log folder for your server, as a subfolder wherever your WAS 5.1 profile is located. RAD should be able to show you where those folders are, and maybe even be able to open the main log file for you.

WAS v7 was released in 2008 and v5.1 would be far older. I would strongly encourage you to upgrade to v8.5 if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

WAS 5.1 is old and is not supported on windows 7. It is highly recommended to upgrade to v7.0 or higher. But if you still want to troubleshoot the logs should be under WAS_HOME/logs//